# How do you bind a combobox to a Database and show values from an enum, or is this the right approach?

Tags: c#

I have some comboboxes on a WinForm that have been populated by an enum:

```
enum valueGenTypes
    {
        None = 0, Prefix = 1, All = 2, Abbreviation = 3, Number = 4
    }
```

I have one combobox that is Bound to a field in the database that is a value of 0-4.

I've wired up the combobox datasource to the enum:

```
valGenTypeID.Properties.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(valueGenTypes));
```

I get a drop down of the values, however, they don't save or reflect what is in the database.
Forgive me if this sounds dumb, but so far it looks like I can only have the drop down linked to the enum or the DB individually(with predefined values in the combobox).

Is there a way to bridge the relationship between:

DBField = 0

ComboBox displays = "None"

Should I be using an enum, or is this even the right approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values that you want to select to the enum values, but you will want to bind the `EditValue` of the Combobox to the Database field that you are wanting to manipulate.

Comment: It's bound. I'm getting a value (2 for example) when I run through the form load. For some reason, it does not show or translate to any enum value in the combobox.

Comment: I figured out my problem. We are using CSLA with an OR mapper. I had to populate the enum on the OR object, then reference the OR object (table name) in the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
valGenTypeID.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(valueGenTypes));
```

then you have to add the databinding to the combobox:

```
valGenTypeID.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", ClassWithValGen, "ValGenField", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. We are using CSLA with an OR mapper. I had to define and populate the enum on the OR object, then reference the OR object (table name) in the datasource.

Basically, the enum had to be at the object level, rather than the UI (form level).

Thanks for your replies!